# Prevent the closure of typeahed.js

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-typeahead, typeahead.js

Is it possible to prevent the closure of the typeahed div (that appear after typing below the input), when I select an element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is ugly but does the job. Note it may break in future versions of typeahead, of course:

http://jsfiddle.net/5fnX7/

Basically you override `DropdownView`'s `close()` method:

```
$(".tt").data("ttView").dropdownView.close = function() { };
```